# create new DataBase & fill with another DataBase

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have a Problem in **C# windows program** that is I can't work with 2 database those are
simple database in tables and Data. in this Project I want to **open Access DataBase** and **Create New Access DataBase** with another Name But **with Same Tables And Columns And Rows** and fill with Source Data that is in Source Database.

I can't read from source DB and insert into new destination DataBase. the sorce code is below please Help me to Complete this Project, thanks a lot.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
    cn.ConnectionString = @"provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"data source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName;
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cn.Open();
    DataTable table = cn.GetSchema("Tables");

    int i = 0;
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        if ((string)row["TABLE_TYPE"] == "TABLE")
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"]);
            Tables[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            listBox1.Items.Add(Tables[i]);
            i++;
            n++;
        }
    }
}
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conne = new OleDbConnection();
    conne.ConnectionString = @"provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"data source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName;
    conne.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conne;
    DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from " + comboBox1.Text;
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adapter.Fill(Dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Dt;
    dataGridView1.Visible = true;
    conne.Close();
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "accdb|*.accdb";
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Access DataBase File";
    saveFileDialog1.FileName = strFileName;
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    System.IO.File.Copy(openFileDialog1.FileName, saveFileDialog1.FileName);

    ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
    cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + saveFileDialog1.FileName);
    Console.WriteLine("Database Created Successfully");
    OleDbConnection connsave = new OleDbConnection();
    connsave.ConnectionString = @"provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"data source=" + saveFileDialog1.FileName;
    connsave.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmdsave = new OleDbCommand();
    cmdsave.Connection = connsave;

    OleDbConnection connopen = new OleDbConnection();
    connopen.ConnectionString = @"provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"data source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName;
    connopen.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmdopen = new OleDbCommand();
    cmdopen.Connection = connopen;

    int i = 0;

    foreach (string strtablename in Tables)
    {
        if (i < n)
        {
            cmdsave.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [" + Tables[i] + "]";
            cmdsave.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmdsave.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [" + Tables[i] + "]";
            cmdsave.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmdopen.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + Tables[i] + "]";
            cmdopen.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmdsave.CommandText = "INSErT INTO [" + Tables[i] + "]";
            cmdsave.ExecuteNonQuery();                       
            i++;
        }
    }
    connopen.Close();
    connsave.Close();
    textBox2.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("DataBase Save Sucessfull in \"" + textBox2.Text + "\"");
}
```

Comment: MS Access is file based. Why not just copy the file?

Comment: this Project should be Use ONLY SQL Statment for Example SELECT , INSERT, ...

Comment: Why? File.Move is one line of code in C#.

Comment: I Have Code for Copy But I Must be use only sql Statment . the code for copy is :System.IO.File.Copy(openFileDialog1.FileName, saveFileDialog1.FileName);

Comment: You only generate an empty insert statement per table. You should use the result of the SELECT statement to build insert statements to run in the target database.

Comment: How use the result of SELECT statement ?please help me with example or code .

Comment: System.IO.File.Copy(openFileDialog1.FileName, saveFileDialog1.FileName);  Am i missing something?  You are already copying files.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute an `INSERT INTO` statement using the `IN` clause:

```
INSERT INTO DestinationTable (DestinationField)
IN '' [;DATABASE= C:\Users\Rob\Documents\Northwind 2007.accdb]
SELECT SourceField FROM SourceTable
```

They go into more detail here:
http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2009/03/27/accessing-external-data-using-the-in-clause.aspx